UnknownHostException with Quarkus and LocalStack S3
I have quarkus application with an REST endpoint to upload file to S3.
With devservices by default I can see localstack container running.
I am trying to build s3client as below and the application launches fine.
public S3AsyncClient getS3Client() {
        AwsBasicCredentials credentials = AwsBasicCredentials.create("test-key", "test-secret");
        return S3AsyncClient.builder().credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(credentials))
        .endpointOverride(URI.create("http://localhost:4566"))
        .region(Region.AP_SOUTH_1)
        .build();
    }

When the request is sent getting UnKnownHost exception.
"Received an UnknownHostException when attempting to interact with a service. See cause for the exact endpoint that is failing to resolve. If this is happening on an endpoint that previously worked, there may be a network connectivity issue or your DNS cache could be storing endpoints for too long."
Container View
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                         COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS                   PORTS                                              NAMES
8a060b1ef175   localstack/localstack:3.0.1   "docker-entrypoint.sh"   3 minutes ago   Up 3 minutes (healthy)   4510-4559/tcp, 5678/tcp, 0.0.0.0:50263->4566/tcp   epic_chandrasekhar
d8fee11b5eee   testcontainers/ryuk:0.6.0     "/bin/ryuk"              3 minutes ago   Up 3 minutes             0.0.0.0:50261->8080/tcp                            testcontainers-ryuk-40638bfc-187f-4540-a786-ab1bc49e63b9

Why is it throwing unknownhost exception ?

Where is the s3 client application running? On your host or in a different container?

the application is running on host machine

Try to configure the Amazon S3 connection in your Quarkus application, especially when using a local endpoint (like localstack) something like this:

Add this in your application.properties file:

quarkus.s3.sync-client.type=apache
quarkus.s3.aws.region=us-east-1
quarkus.s3.aws.credentials.type=default
quarkus.s3.path-style-access=false

%dev.quarkus.s3.endpoint-override=http://localhost:4566
%dev.quarkus.s3.path-style-access=true
%dev.quarkus.s3.aws.credentials.type=static
%dev.quarkus.s3.aws.credentials.static-provider.access-key-id=test-key
%dev.quarkus.s3.aws.credentials.static-provider.secret-access-key=test-secret


Ensure you have the correct dependency in your pom.xml:

<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkiverse.amazonservices</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-amazon-s3</artifactId>
</dependency>

Here's the documentation s3 quarkus

This began happening with version 2.18 of the S3 library, when the bucket value formatting changed. Version 2.17 didn't have this error. Set .forcePathStyle(true) on the S3AsyncClientBuilder to revert to the 2.17 behavior
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/3524
